# Solr with String and Text filed Queries .?

Tags: solr

```
   <field name="NAME" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
      <field name="NAMETEXT" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
```

> My Search Query is
>
> NAME:22 
>   NAMETEXT:22 both query i tried.. It returns results with name
>   "index 2.2", "indexch 2.2", index3 2.2
>
> Why its returning this values..

Answer (score 1):

Because your [WordDelimiter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) converts "2.2" into "22" and these terms are matched with your query.